# How to make a function to Compare Strings Without Case Sensitivity, without strcmpi()

Tags: c

My question is about How to make a function to compare strings without case sensitivity, without using `strcmpi()` in C.

Comment: using `strcasecmp`?

Comment: show your effort

Comment: ... using `strxfrm`?

Comment: ... using `strcoll`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement your own:

```
#define TO_LOWER(c) ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c - 'A' + 'a' : c)

int my_strcmpi(char* str1, char* str2) {
    while (*str1 && *str2 && TO_LOWER(*str1) == TO_LOWER(*str2))
    {
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
    return TO_LOWER(*str1) - TO_LOWER(*str2);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Ü.  On an EBCDIC platform this will declare "æ" equal to "¦".  (The latter is in the range 'A' to 'Z'.)  Use `tolower` - it handles all of these cases (it doesn't handle ß, but that is another world of pain).

Comment: Or define the macro with `('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') ? c ^ ('A' ^ 'a') : c`

Comment: How about using `TO_LOWER` before subtracting the characters for the return value?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, why would `c ^ ('A' ^'a')` be better than `c - ('A' -'a')`? I think subtraction is clearer, but maybe I'm missing something here

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Still doesn't work for EBCDIC, and the obvious question is "why?"

Comment: It will handle both ASCII and EBCDIC.

Comment: @Gerhardh, you're right, omitting those `TO_LOWER`s can invert the result when the strings are not equal. Fixed.

Comment: @MartinBonner Having code break on an EBCDIC system is not a bad thing, it is a feature. The problem is in the EBCDIC symbol table, not the code. You can add a static assert `'Z' - 'A'` to prevent the code from compiling on stupidly designed systems. Providing compatibility to such systems in the year 2018 is nonsense.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It correctly handles all uppercase letters in EBCDIC ***but*** it also changes some other characters that are not uppercase letters.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree.  Using `tolower` (which must be part of the C implementation) is both simpler and more portable.  (And it will handle Ü if your locale uses that.)

Comment: @MartinBonner No. If you are using an extended character set, you will be using `towlower` and `wchar_t`. That C allows all manner of symbol tables for `char` is mostly historical reasons, from the days when evil things like "extended ASCII" walked the earth.

Comment: @Lundin "You will be using `towupper`" - that's remarkable presumptious.  ISO-8859-1 covers North America and most of Europe; yes, if you want full I18n you need to use `wchar_t`, but a lot of people don't.

Comment: @MartinBonner The problem isn't if it will fit in 8 bits or not. The problem is all the trashy symbol tables that have been shown into said 8 bit format over the years, making the use of `char` for anything beyond 7 bit ASCII completely non-reliable.

Comment: @MartinBonner `('A' <= c && c <= 'Z') ? c ^ ('A' ^ 'a') : c ` is only applied against upper case in both ASCII and EBCDIC.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You realize that A-Z are not continguous in EBCDIC.   '¦' is greater than A and less than Z.  You will transform it to 'æ'.

Comment: @MartinBonner yes, you are correct there. You would actually need to protect 3 zones `A-I`, `J-R` and `S-Z` to eliminate the brace and backslash and non-contiguous areas.